# GCM ASP.NET Android Tutorial

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, google-cloud-messaging

I am planning a push notification service and have a current "test project" working with Windows Phone.  I am now experimenting with Android and am not having much luck.  Has anyone created a step-by-step tutorial on how to use GCM with ASP.NET (C#) for an Android application?  Microsoft has great examples for their push notification services, but I'm not getting a basic, detailed level tutorial on doing so with Android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have googled to find these:

- [ASP.net and GCM](http://steveloper.com/android-google-cloud-messaging-and-asp-net/)
- [CodeProject Tutorial to use GCM for ASP.NET using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/434338/Android-GCM-Push-Notification)

You should find the [official tutorial cum guide](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) to start GCM very easy..Follow it step by step.Then implement the server logic once your device is registered to trigger push notification.

Basically, once your device id is registered.You need to save this id to database according to your logic and later you can send push by referring to these device ids.. such as:

```
AndroidGCMPushNotification apnGCM = new AndroidGCMPushNotification();

string strResponse =
apnGCM.SendNotification(deviceID,
"Test Push Notification message ")
```

Comment: First Link "Asp.Net and GCM" is not more working...